# How can I legally watch all uk sports without sky or a tv aerial

Tags: football, boxing

I want to watch the uk premier league matches, however, I have no way of getting a tv aerial or a satellite dish for sky. I cannot get bt sport either. My only option is to get something online.

I have tried using the NowTV app online, however, I found I could only watch a match live, and the coverage was too limited.

Ideally, I would like some way of being able to watch all the matches any time I want, so both live and recorded. Also, it would be good to watch some of the commentary shows as well.

Additionally, I want to get into Boxing, but I have no way of watching that at the moment.

I am more bothered about watching recorded games than live games. When the game is live, I find it hard to make sure I am watching the game at the right time. I end up missing all the games.

I have thought about using Kodi or some other streaming site, however, this sounds kind of dodgey. I am happy to pay for a subscription to a paid service, even up to £50 a month. I just don't have any options at the moment.

How should I approach this problem? At the moment, I think I'm probably just not going to watch sports altogether, until I can get my own house with a tv aerial and satellite for sky. I don't want to use anything dodgey or shadey, just official stuff, please. Also, I live in the UK.

Comment: Welcome to Sports.SE! This site doesn't condone piracy, so any answers recommending illegal methods will just get deleted anyway.